# Push Page but keep hamburger-menu-icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a **MasterDetailPage** and its **Detail** is `navigationPage1`. I want to Push `navigationPage2` over `navigationPage1` but keep the menu icon showing. How can I do that?

I already tried both `PushAsync` and `PushModalAsync`. I tried using `nonNavigationPage2` (which left *an* icon, but not the hamburger, the left arrow one).

Comment: When using the MasterDetail pattern and pushing pages to the navigation stack, the native behaviour is to show an arrow. So, why do you want to change the behaviour? Keep in mind that Xamarin.Forms intends to target the native behaviour of each platform. Thus, if you really want to change the behaviour, you should probably consider writing your own custom renderer. Otherwise, instead of pushing to the navigation stack, then set the [`Detail Property`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.Detail/) to the `Page` you want to show.

Comment: @Demitrian What I want to accomplish is to let a user use the back button within one "page" of the Master page, and yet be able to easily go to another page of the Master page without losing the stack of the first child page. But I guess, by your response, that that's not supported out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to have both an arrow and a hamburger? No, that is not supported in the current version of the SDK since Xamarin.Forms aims at the native behaviour of each platform, and what you're asking for is outside of that scope.

Comment: You can still access the Master page via swiping from left to right on the pushed page.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the hamburger instead of the back button by using this code:

```
  NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(nextPage, false);
  ((NavigationPage)page).PushAsync(nextPage);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code:

```
YourMasterDetailPage.Detail = new NagivationPage(new page1);
```

and when you click in another one u use again

```
YourMasterDetailPage.Detail = new NagivationPage(new page2);
```